# Invalid URL: ./. coming up when clicking on Advanced permissions>settings>permission levels

Tags: permissions

When I navigate from `site actions>Advanced Permissions>Settings>Permission Levels`, I am receiving error

> as Invalid URL: ./.

We have 4 servers in the farm and one of them is working fine.
How do I trouble shoot this issue?
I have changed few lines in the webconfig file to display the whole error message, but as I am new it was not displaying the whole info of the error.
My question is how do I know what kind of error is it.
And how do I know what is missing from other servers since one server is working fine.

Comment: Pls check the ULS log C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Logs (or hive 15 if SP2013)

Answer (score 0):

With "four servers in the farm" I guess you have 1 SQL Server, 1 App server and 2 Web Front End Servers. To deal with a single server failure you need to know which server your actually browsing.

You can do this the hard way, and turn off one of the WFE:s as in shutting down all web sites in IIS. Then you know for sure which server you're on, and can access logs knowing for certain what server caused it.

You can also do it the soft way and browse to the server IP-address since its unique for every server in your domain. When your accessing a server through its IP-address, you know which server replies on your request and can start looking for errors form there.

A few tip as you continue:

1. Do both servers have the same SharePoint version, patch and upgrade in place, and have PSCONFIG been run on both servers since last patch session?
2. Make sure web.config are equal on both servers
3. Make sure you're using the same app pool account on the web site on both servers
4. Check the hosts-file and remove pointers to this server for the actual web site. Mapping should be made on the DNS.
5. Check the hive content on the servers and make sure they are equal
6. Are windows features, services and possibly other third party components in place on both servers and configured equal? (I know this is a tough call, but if you're done with 1-5 you're running out of options).

Answer (score 0):

If it is Sharepoint 2013, it might be worth checking to see if the 'minimal download strategy' site feature is activated, and deactivate it and see if that solves your URL issue.

It's caused issues for me before.